# sublimeREPL - "can't open file '$file_basename'"

Tags: python-3.x, sublimerepl

When I try to execute more than an operation using `SublimeREPL` and *Python3* I get :
`C:/Users/Name/Anaconda3/envs/keras/python.exe: can't open file '$file_basename': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198563/no-such-file-or-directory-error-happens-when-start-sublimerepl-python) answer I have modified the `sublime-settings` file adding `"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};C:/Users/Simone/Anaconda3/envs/keras"}`.

I have also add the path `C:/Users/Name/Anaconda3/envs/keras/python.exe` in `Main.sublime-menu` file, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Hmm can you edit the problem statement and paste a bit more of the changes that you've made in the `Main.sublime-menu file`? In addition `C:/Users/Name/Anaconda3/envs/keras/python.exe` is not the same as `C:/Users/Simone/Anaconda3/envs/keras`. Was `Name` a placeholder for your post?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to modify you sublime-setttings file. I suppose that you have your subl configured to run with python3 but it doesn't matter. 
When you use ctrl + b for running your code, you must be sure that you have something written. Is only that, if you use ctrl + b but you don't have anything in your code file is normal that you were obtaining that error.

Answer (score 1):

When your cursor not in the current python file [may be in output panel of the `SublimeREPL` or may be in empty tab/file] and if you are running

> `Tools->SublimeREPL->python->python - RUN currentfile`

then you may get below error. Because there is no file's path for that output panel file or for an empty file.

> C:/Users/Name/Anaconda3/envs/keras/python.exe: can't open file
>   '$file_basename': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

So, focus your cursor in the current python file and try it again.

This may be one of the case.I faced this problem and after few trials i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

did you save the file?

I have had the same problem. I saved the file and it worked