# Python3.6 not displaying output in Sublime-Text3

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Python3.6 Code]

When inputting the name Python3.6 is not displaying the required output

And here is the image of my build-system

[image: Python3.6 Build System]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the text you are typing into Sublime Text is not being passed to the Python interpreter. From the program's perspective, it is still waiting for input.

I don't think it's possible to modify this behavior in Sublime Text. This limitation is part of the text editor's functionality, and hopefully it will be addressed in a future release.

Comment: So what to do to fix it.

Comment: @Slothfulwave10 You can use this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input (its a temporary workaround)

Answer (score 2):

Here I got the solution :-

1. I installed SublimeRepl package in sublime-text3
2. Then I edited python file in sublimerepl, for this refer:- [Sublimerepl-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198563/no-such-file-or-directory-error-happens-when-start-sublimerepl-python)

3.Then I run my python file through SublimeRepl, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
print('Hello {0}'.format(name))
```

and make sure using terminal to run your .py file

Comment: This is not the issue. OP is using python 3.6, which supports the format string syntax.

Comment: Yes the format is correct, but using sublime can cause bugs when dealing with input(). Using Terminal will give you the correct output.